# Why "bash -c" can't receive full list of arguments?

Tags: bash, shell

I have next two scripts:

**test.sh:**

```
echo "start"
echo $@
echo "end"
```

**run.sh:**

```
echo "parameters from user:"
echo $@
echo "start call test.sh:"
bash -c "./test.sh $@"
```

**Execute above run.sh:**

```
$ ./run.sh 1 2
parameters from user:
1 2
start call test.sh:
start
1
end
```

You could see although I pass 2 arguments to `run.sh`, the `test.sh` just receive the first argument.

But, if I change `run.sh` to next which just drop `bash -c`:

```
echo "parameters from user:"
echo $@
echo "start call test.sh:"
./test.sh $@
```

The behavior becomes as expected which `test.sh` receive 2 arguments:

```
$ ./run.sh 1 2
parameters from user:
1 2
start call test.sh:
start
1 2
end
```

**Question:**

For some reason, I have to use `bash -c` in my full scenario, then could you kindly tell me what's wrong here? How I could fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because of the quoting of the arguments is in wrong place. When you run a sequence of commands inside `bash -c`, think of that as it being a full shell script in itself, and need to pass arguments accordingly. From the bash manual

> If Bash is started with the `-c` option (see [Invoking Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Invoking-Bash)), then `$0` is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present. Otherwise, it is set to the filename used to invoke Bash, as given by argument zero.

But if one notices your command below,

```sh
bash -c "./test.sh $@"
```

when your expectation was to pass the arguments to the `test.sh`, inside `'..'`, but the `$@` inside double-quotes expanded pre-maturely, undergoing word-splitting to produce the first argument value only, i.e. value of `$1`

But even when you have fixed it by using single quotes as below, it still can't work, because remember the contents  passed to `-c` is evaluated in its own shell context and needs arguments passed explicitly,

```sh
set -- 1 2
bash -c 'echo $@'       # Both the cases still don't work, as the script
bash -c 'echo "$@"'     # inside '-c' is still not passed any arguments
```

To fix, the above, you need an explicit passing of arguments the contents inside `-c` as below. The `_` (underscore) character represents the pathname of the shell invoked to execute the script (in this case bash). More at [Bash Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Variables) on the manual

```sh
set -- 1 2
bash -c 'printf "[%s]\n" "$@"' _ "$@"
[1]
[2]
```

So to fix your script, in `run.sh`, pass the arguments as

```sh
bash -c './test.sh "$@"' _ "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the accept one, find another solution just now. If add `-x` when call the `run.sh`, I could see next:

```
$ bash -x ./run.sh 1 2
+ echo 'parameters from user:'
parameters from user:
+ echo 1 2
1 2
+ echo 'start call test.sh:'
start call test.sh:
+ bash -c './test.sh 1' 2
start
1
end
```

So, it looks `bash -c "./test.sh $@"` is interpreted as `bash -c './test.sh 1' 2`.

Inspired from this, I tried to use `$*` to replace `$@`, which then just pass all params as a single parameter, then with next it also works well:

**run.sh:**

```
echo "parameters from user:"
echo $*
echo "start call test.sh:"
bash -c "./test.sh $*"
```

**Execution:**

```
$ bash -x ./run.sh 1 2
+ echo 'parameters from user:'
parameters from user:
+ echo 1 2
1 2
+ echo 'start call test.sh:'
start call test.sh:
+ bash -c './test.sh 1 2'
start
1 2
end
```